# Cross platform COM development 

Tags: windows, com, winapi, dcom

COM as we know is language and platform independent standard, but all the time I see only articles on developing COM components on Windows. Could you share your thoughts on how to develop a true cross-platform application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written code using COM on Mac and Unix, with no supporting libraries.  You actually just need C++.  It's basically a protocol.

However, if you really want to write using cross-platform COM, I suggest you look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't opposed to commercial tools, MainSoft's MainWin let's you integrate Visual Studio COM/ATL development in a Linux environment.  You actually develop on your windows box but the binaries are compiled on the native Linux box.  You can check it out here:

http://www.mainsoft.com/content/mainsoft-enterprise-edition-overview

I have personally used this at my company with great success.